# Trouble connecting to vtiger 6 using the vtwsclib 1.4

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

i'm using vtiger CRM 6 and trying to connect my android application with the vtiger using the webservices i'm using the vtwsclib 1.4
nothing works for me...here's my doLogin code
am i missing something? 
plz help!

```
<?php
include_once('vtwsclib/Vtiger/WSClient.php');
$url = 'http://'http://en.vtiger.com/wip';
$client = new Vtiger_WSClient($url);
$login = $client->doLogin($userName, $userAccessKey););
if(!$login){
echo '<pre>'.print_r($client, true).'</pre>';
die("Login Failed");
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a typo in the answer, but this is wrong:

```
$url = 'http://'http://en.vtiger.com/wip';
```

It should be

```
$url = 'http://en.vtiger.com/wip';
```

Answer (score 0):

hey $url is your $host for examle $url='localhost'; or $host='localhost'; $url=$host;

- You must download and read this documentation to make correct connection via web services with vtiger crm

download from here:

http://forge.vtiger.com/frs/?group_id=181